# Some code for using MySQL database in Java always returnng false / account not being created?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
    public boolean clientExists(Request request) {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM `client_table` WHERE user = ? AND password= ?";
    try {
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        stmt.setString(1, request.getUsername());
        stmt.setBytes(2, request.getPassword());
        ResultSet set = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (set.next()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Creates a user in the database.
 * @param request
 * @return
 */

public boolean createClient(Request request) {
    if (!clientExists(request)) {
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        String exe = "INSERT INTO `client_table`(`id`, `user`, `password`, `create_date`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(exe);
            statement.setString(1, uuid.toString());
            statement.setString(2, request.getUsername());
            statement.setBytes(3, request.getPassword());
            statement.setString(4, getDate());
            statement.executeUpdate(exe);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hi, basically the createClient method does not succesfully create a client, I have no idea what I have done wrong but one of these methods is not working - since an account is never created / a username:password is never accepted.

Can anyone figure out what I've done wrong? I'm using JDBC.

Comment: You say it returns false, which one? What exception messages are printed?

Comment: @TZHX there are no exception messages. It just doesn't CREATE the client.

Comment: Do you know whether you have auto commit turned on or off?  This is a critical piece of information here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen not a clue. I haven't "fiddled" with it, so probably off?

Comment: what type of `id` int or string?

Comment: It's usually on by default, in which case my answer is wrong.  Try calling `connection.commit()` after the insert and see if that fixes it.  If not, then we need another explanation.

Comment: Okay Tim. @YCF_L uuid.toString()

Comment: http://prntscr.com/exd8s4 this is my database.

Comment: Side note: never store passwords in a database like this. Use something like bcrypt to salt and hash them.

Comment: @JBNizet I put the char[] password into an MD5 byte array - should I store it as a BLOB?

Comment: MD5 is a weak, broken hashing algorithm. And it certainly won't protect you from dictionary attacks if you don't combine it with a random salt.

Comment: @JBNizet this is just a small-scale school project -> security isn't too important but has to be "considered" which is why I can use MD5 and explain that if I were to sorta develop this prototype, I would do this, that etc.

Comment: OK, fine. But given that you would use the exact same code with a stronger, not broken hashing algorithm, why not at least use one, instead of the broken MD5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two problems with this code ... or three if you count the possible issue with autocommit.

1. In your `clientExist` method, you are testing to see if an entry exists for an given user AND password.  I think that is wrong.  The "existence" test should not be sensitive to someone providing the correct password.  This could lead to duplicate accounts being created with the same username and different passwords.
2. You don't perform the existence test and the insertion of a new account in the same database transaction.  That means that there is a potential race condition which could lead to the same account being created twice ... independently of the previous problem.

I doubt that these explain your problem with no accounts being created.  Nonetheless, these are bugs that you need to fix.

Note that problem 2 means that you *should not* be running with autocommit enabled, and you *should* be committing or rolling back the transaction explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

one problem i see here is that you are passing string query "exe" in

`statement.executeUpdate(exe);`

instead write this

`statement.executeUpdate();`